# SQL: What is wrong with the following query (generated by WordPress WP_Query, ordering prices)

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, order, sql

Hey there I have the following SQL Query which is generated by WP_Query numeric meta query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_postmeta.meta_value FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) 
WHERE 1=1 
AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'price' 
AND ( mt1.meta_key = 'price' 
AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN '0' AND '9999' ) ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) DESC LIMIT 0, 15
```

The WordPress query - if it helps - is generated like this and it should be correct:

```
array(6) {
  ["orderby"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["price"]=>
    string(4) "DESC"
  }
  ["meta_query"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["relation"]=>
    string(3) "AND"
    ["sortprimary_clause"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["key"]=>
      string(17) "price"
      ["compare"]=>
      string(6) "EXISTS"
      ["type"]=>
      string(7) "numeric"
    }
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["key"]=>
      string(17) "price"
      ["value"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        float(0)
        [1]=>
        float(9999)
      }
      ["compare"]=>
      string(7) "BETWEEN"
      ["type"]=>
      string(7) "numeric"
    }
  }
  ["tax_query"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["relation"]=>
    string(3) "AND"
  }
  ["post_type"]=>
  string(7) "product"
  ["posts_per_page"]=>
  int(15)
  ["paged"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

The result is as follows:

[image: Query result]

As you can see SQL is ordering the values BASICALLY correct however only in the INTEGER size of the prices. The decimal seperator seems to be completely ignored. How can I change the SQL in order to work correctly with floating point numbers. Is it a WordPress issue or can I change WP_Query such that it is working with floating point numbers correctly?

EDIT: I found the Problem! `ORDER BY CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED)` should be `ORDER BY CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS DECIMAL(M,3))`.

So the question is: **How can I change WP_Query to use a decimal value for comparison instead of Integer?**

Comment: I would note that this will be an expensive query to run, the meta query part in particular, if you can make it so that all posts have the price post meta, even if the value is -1 by default, and that you cache the query itself when used, that will go a long way

Comment: @TomJNowell Yeah I guess you are right however the WP_Query object is building this query automatically so there is not much possibilities to influence the SQL? I guess "transients" are the correct way to go if I want to cache the results right?

Comment: Any information about the code that's generating that query, or the page that you're on and what type of page it is might help, `pre_get_posts` can filter the query variables prior to the SQL being generated

Answer (score 1):

Solved. After the edit it was easy. It is allowed to use type => 'decimal(x,x)' in meta_query. Maximum precision is decimal(65,30).

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html

```
array(6) {
  ["orderby"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["uss_product_price"]=>
    string(4) "DESC"
    ["title"]=>
    string(3) "ASC"
  }
  ["meta_query"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["relation"]=>
    string(3) "AND"
    ["sortprimary_clause"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["key"]=>
      string(17) "price"
      ["compare"]=>
      string(6) "EXISTS"
      ["type"]=>
      string(13) "decimal(30,5)"
    }
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["key"]=>
      string(17) "price"
      ["value"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        float(0)
        [1]=>
        float(9999)
      }
      ["compare"]=>
      string(7) "BETWEEN"
      ["type"]=>
      string(7) "decimal(30,5)"
    }
  }
  ["tax_query"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["relation"]=>
    string(3) "AND"
  }
  ["post_type"]=>
  string(7) "product"
  ["posts_per_page"]=>
  int(15)
  ["paged"]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```